# "Mixed" search in a pandas series

Tags: pandas, search, series

Things are moving along well with this learning curve with Pandas and Python. Therefore, I have the "meat" of the searching which I'm sure will be a challange.

Let's say, for example, there is a pandas series below of work hours. I have the code which, when the user input matches the values of the work hours, returns the date as follows:

```
num_srch = "12 22 04 06 09 04"
num_mask = pwrDF['Work Hours'] == num_srch
num_match = pwrDF.loc[num_mask, "Work Date"].values

if len(pwrDF[(pwrDF['Work Hours'] == num_srch)]) >0:
    num_match = num_match[0]
    print('These hours match this date:\n ', num_match)
else:
    print('No hours match what you entered')

       Work Date    Work hours
0     03/10/2023  12 22 04 06 09 04
1     03/09/2023  02 13 29 58 69 05
2     03/08/2023  03 14 05 08 09 06
```

and this works perfectly! However, if the order is different than how the data is in the series, then no output is given.

In this example, if the search is `04 04 22 12 06 09` it will not return the date. I understand that is the behavior, however, the challenge will be to learn how to go through all the work hours combinations.

Answer (score 1):

You can compare sets created by splitting values by space, then order is not important, but duplicates are removed:

```
num_srch = "12 22 04 06 09 04"
s = set(num_srch.split())
print (s)
{'12', '22', '04', '06', '09'}

num_mask = pwrDF['Work Hours'].apply(lambda x: set(x.split())).eq(s)
num_match = pwrDF.loc[num_mask, "Work Date"]

if num_match.any():
    num_match = num_match[0]
    print('These hours match this date:\n ', num_match)
else:
    print('No hours match what you entered')
```

Another idea is compare by sorted values:

```
num_srch = "12 22 04 06 09 04"

t = tuple(sorted(num_srch.split()))
print (t)
('04', '04', '06', '09', '12', '22')

num_mask = pwrDF['Work Hours'].apply(lambda x: tuple(sorted(x.split()))).eq(t)
num_match = pwrDF.loc[num_mask, "Work Date"]

if len(pwrDF[(pwrDF['Work Hours'] == num_srch)]) >0:
    num_match = num_match[0]
    print('These hours match this date:\n ', num_match)
else:
    print('No hours match what you entered')
```